# Eclipse ADT - library project cannot use own resources?

Tags: adt

I've written an app with many custom icons in the 'res' folder. I've recently abstracted much of the code into an Android library, including buttons using the resource-icons. And it's gone pear-shaped.

Specifically, when a library class refers to a resource, it references the com.example.library.R class (not the real package name!). This works fine for compiling, but when I run the app on a device, the com.example.library.R class isn't in the apk, so I get a ClassNotFoundException. I gather library projects don't put their R class into their jar file, so that explains its absence from the apk.

My question is, if I code a button in a library project, how can I refer to an icon in its resources? Is this possible? If so, how? If not, are there work-arounds? (I can't be the first person to hit this problem!)

Answer (score 0):

I've coded a work-around, all in java. Other solutions I've seen for similar problems involve jiggling eclipse/adt's is-library settings, or otherwise relying on flakiness in the IDE. Here's my approach...

(1) Have the icons in both the library's and app's res folders.

(2) Copy the R.java file from the library's gen folder into a package in the src folder, and rename it RR.java.

(3) In the app's main activity, write static initialisation code that copies each value from the app's R class to the library's RR class.

(4) Throughout the library, use the RR class rather than the R class.

It's ugly, but it seems to work.